# instead of URL the url bar has the Port number on opening IE with selenium Webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to work on IE With selenium webdriver.
But when my URL Opens instead of the URL it gives a port in the URL bar
and it gives internet Explorer cannot display the page.

My code is

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" );
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the IE directly in your code. You should not use the normal IE (iexplore.exe) file.

You should use the `InternetExplorerDriver` file which you can download from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

32 Bit: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.42.0.zip

64 Bit: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/IEDriverServer_x64_2.42.0.zip

Once you download them provide them as below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "PATH_OF_IEDriverServer.exe" );
```